# Is an old smartphone display usable with MCU

Tags: microcontroller, display, smartphones

Can a smartphone display be reused? Do these displays use some standard pinout or not?
Display has this circuit on the back and a 24pin connector.

[image: circuit on the back of the screen]

I couldn't find anything about the ic. It's a display from an old lumia 535 to be specific.

[image: display]

Comment: yes. no. ... not worth the time and money to try to make work

Comment: @jsotola and if you do get it to work you'll never find another one.

Comment: If the Lumia is still working you can try observe the bus/data with logic analyser and find the pattern. Most of display drivers are pretty same so you can inspire yourself by some common datasheet to get some starting point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Can a smartphone display be reused?*

Yes, if you have the right driver board for it. However it's not many reverse-engineered display circuits out there, and manufacturers have no interest in releasing blueprints so driver boards are not common.

*Do these displays use some standard pinout or not?*

No. That's the least of concern anway, due to the above.